# Emacs Evil Mode Insert Key is Lagging

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I've recently switched from using vimpulse to evil and have noticed a very strange and annoying behavior.

I will be in command mode and hit the 'i' key, which should put me in insert mode.
However, what happens instead is that I stay in command mode and my next keystroke is interpreted in that mode.

If I type slower I usually get the correct behavior, but not always.

Note I am using emacs in a terminal not in X, but I'm on a LAN.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the first step is to check with `C-h k i RET` that `i` is calling the evil-insert function and wasn't overridden by something else. Is that the case ?

Comment: It has not been overridden.

Comment: Can you try in X so than we can isolate the pbs ? (you don't use keychord mode right ?)

Comment: I took a very critical look at my .emacs file and found that I was enabling viper before enabling evil. I think vimpulse or another one of its ilk required this at one point. Evil does not seem to need it though, so I've removed all of the viper stuff and the problem seems to have gone away. I'll work for a day before posting an answer and declaring victory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that having viper active along side evil was the culprit. After disabling all things viper the lag has disappeared and I can be productive!

Comment: If this worked for you please accept your own answer. :)